# why "num = 1" inside the loop is not incrementing?

Tags: python

I was debugging the code and I don't understand why the num variable inside the for-loop is not incrementing and only (1) is incrementing ?

def numpat(n):

```
    num = 1                            ----- (1)


    for i in range(n):

        num = 1                        ------ (2)

        for j in range(i + 1):
            print(num, end=" ")
            num = num + 1               ----- (3)

        print("\r")
```

Comment: can you give more insight on this?  When I set n = 10, I get the same result as the answers below.  Can you define what you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify your question. I would recommend reading the following article: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: Thank you for comments, i'm beginner here and i'm learning.

Answer (score 3):

Is the below output not what you expected?

```
In [1]: n = 5                                                                                 

In [2]: for i in range(n): 
   ...:  
   ...:     num = 1 
   ...:  
   ...:     for j in range(i + 1): 
   ...:         print(num, end=" ") 
   ...:         num = num + 1 
   ...:  
   ...:     print("\r") 
   ...:                                                                                       
1 
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 5
```

Edit: Counterfactual output if n=1 wasn't in the inner loop.

```
In [1]: n = 5                                                                   

In [2]: num = 1                                                                 

In [3]: for i in range(n): 
   ...:     for j in range(i + 1): 
   ...:         print(num, end=" ") 
   ...:         num = num + 1 
   ...:     print("\r") 
   ...:                                                                         
1 
2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: This is what I got too.

Comment: Yes, i'm getting the expected output but i'm not understanding why we need to "num = 1" inside the loop?

Comment: If you don't then `num` will just continue to across lines; see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're setting the value of `num` to 1 everytime after the first loop i.e `for i in range(n):`. You can ignore that step and it'll work just fine.

Comment: I got it.Thank you very much.